# calculate :$\sum _{n=1}^{oo}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}+(n+1)\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}+(n+1)\sqrt{n}}$$

? Can someone help and explain too?

Comment: Rationalize $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and notice that is a telescopic series.

Comment: partial fraction decomposition and telescoping series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}+(n+1)\sqrt{n}}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})} \\
&= \frac{-\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}+(n+1)\sqrt{n}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=1$$

Comment: Nicely done.  (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot !.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)=1$$